# Use of unresolved identifier 'enumerate' after Swift Migration

Tags: ios

I have an array, called customAnnotationsArray, in which I am appending a class (Annotations) to.  This class, Annotations, is a subclass of MKAnnotation and NSObject.  In my previous Swift version, the code `for (index, value) in enumerate(customAnnotationArray)` worked wonderfully to extract the pin's index.  Now, it is saying that there is "Use of unresolved identifier 'enumerate'.  Ive researched a ton and cannot find any resources.  How do I fix this?

```
//Annotations array (gets populated with annotations on data load)
var customAnnotationArray = [Annotations]()


//When tapping the MKAnnotationView.
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView,
             calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

    let theAnnotation = view.annotation

    //ERROR BELOW IN enumerate "Use of unresolved identifier 'enumerate'
    for (index, value) in enumerate(customAnnotationArray) {

        if value === theAnnotation {
            //print("The annotation's array index is \(index)")

            //Im passing these variables in prepareForSegue to VC
            markerIndex = index
            addressSelected = addressArray[index]
        }
    }

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "updateRecordVC")
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)  
}



//Annotations class if that helps.
class Annotations: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let title: String?
    let locationName: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let pinColor: MKPinAnnotationColor

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, locationName: String, pinColor:MKPinAnnotationColor) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.locationName = locationName
        self.pinColor = pinColor      
        super.init()
    }

    var subtitle: String? {
        return locationName
    }

    func currentPinColor(_ currentUser: Double) -> MKPinAnnotationColor?   {
        switch currentUser {
        case 0:
            return .green
        case 1:
            return .purple
        default:
            return .green
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using the `enumerated()` method instead:

```
for (index, value) in customAnnotationArray.enumerated()
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for...

Comment: thank you!  Im surprised Xcode didnt have a quick fix option for this

Comment: Thanks bro... +1 for you